# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php

I am a completely clueless about PHP and attempted to add this in regardless.

Visiting `/blog-1/index.html` directly should redirect me to `/blog-2/index.html` or atleast that the idea...

```
<?php
global $url = "/blog-1/index.html";
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == global $url) {
    header('Location: /blog-2/index.html'); 
    exit();
}
?>
```

I keep getting -

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';'

Any help is truly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be

```
<?php
    global $url = "/blog-1/index.html"; //no need of global here 
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == $url) 
    {
         header('Location: /blog-2/index.html'); 
         exit();
    }
?>
```

`if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == global $url) {` here `global $url` is the culprit

Comment: @Akintunde Done i was editing my answer when you wrote this...

Comment: Thanks works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

First error: In this code that you wrote used global $url, why you used. this definition is not need just define variable like this:

```
$url = "/blog-1/index.html";
```

Second error: create your if conditions:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == $url) {
    header('Location: /blog-2/index.html'); 
    exit();
}
```

When it is necessary to use global, for example you define a variable in your PHP file and do not want to pass that to your function. in this cases you can use global in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Try use of below  code..........

```
<?php
global $url = "/blog-1/index.html";
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ==  $url) {
header('Location: /blog-2/index.html'); 
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: You are welcome